# Android - Using realm in non activity class

Tags: android, realm

I am creating an application for Android. I am using Realm as a Database. Realm working fine in the whole app. Now I want to insert some data when from "NotificationExtender" class (This will help to receive and customise onesignal notification).  Which leads to outOfMemory error How can I handle this.

My sample code:
In My Notification class I am doing this

```
RealmLibrary.insertMessageToDBFromNotificationReceiver(
                                jsonObject.getString("data"),
                                jsonObject.getString("groupKey"),
                                jsonObject.getString("groupKey"),
                                 mContext);
```

And in my RealmLibrary class:

```
Realm realm = getRealm(applicationContext);

realm.beginTransaction();
    ChatMessages chatmsg = realm.where(ChatMessages.class)
            .equalTo("gUid", gUID).findFirst();

    int count = 0;

    if (chatmsg == null) {
        // Create an new object
        chatmsg = realm.createObject(ChatMessages.class);

        count = 1;
        chatmsg.setgUid(gUID);
    } else {

    }

    realm.commitTransaction();
```

Also my getRealm method:

```
 public static Realm getRealm(Context context) {

        return  Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    }
```

How can i handle this outOf memory. Please anyone tell me which code leads to the error. Which is the not efficient code..

Note : it is just a sample code. If any details needed pls leave your comments.

Comment: It'd be useful to see the logcat, probably

Comment: Ok sure give me a minute. I will update the question

Comment: You're most definitely not closing your Realm instance on background threads. Also you should use `chatmsg = realm.createObject(ChatMessages.class, gUID);` if gUID is a primary key.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce No I am not using primary key. But yes I didn't close db How to close db?.  realm.close() ? I tried this too.  But no use

Comment: You [have to close all opened instances on the background thread](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/how-to-use-realm-for-android-like-a-champ-and-how-to-tell-if-youre-doing-it-wrong-ac4f66b7f149#.cdw36vm0q).   Typically I open only one instance per thread.

Answer (score 0):

I currently have only 49 reputation points, so I can't comment this. Just an idea (maybe this is stupid, tell me if so and I'll delete this answer), you may want to add and use LeakCanary and check if you have some memory leaks:

```
dependencies {
   debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta2'
   releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
   testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
 }
```

and

```
public class ExampleApplication extends Application {

  @Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    LeakCanary.install(this);
  }
}
```

(use `LeakCanary.install(getApplication());` if your Activity doesn't extends `Application`)